# Out of Office for Disabled User

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

We disable there exchange email and that in turn disabled the account in AD. We would like to set up auto out of office reply for the employee has left the company. is this possible if her account is disabled?
BTW , I have been using Exchange Server 2013.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of Office reply is not the best solution for this. In order to use this feature you would need to keep the mailbox accepting mails, and the reply is only sent once for the same recipient. It's not a clear indication that no-one reads the mail.

I find it even worse to automatically forward someone's `first.last@example.com` mail to another person as it may have confidentially issues.

If you disable the mailbox, everyone will get an error that the mailbox doesn't exist anymore. That is a clear indication to search for new contact information from your web site.

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, if you disable the mailbox in Exchange server side, it would remove the Exchange attributes for the user account but leave the user account in Active Directory.  The mailbox is then also left in the Exchange mailbox database until the retention period has lapsed, then it is removed permanently.

And OOF is a server side feature, if you disable the mailbox, it would not be able to configure it for the user.

When sending mail to this disabled mailbox, usually it would return the message:“ the email address is no longer valid”.